# Unwanted white space on left of UIScrollView on iPhone X

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, background-color, iphone-x, safearealayoutguide

`UIScrollView` works fine without the white space on the left on all iPads or iPhones except for iPhone X. How can I remove the white space?

I use storyboards. Bounce On Scroll/Zoom are all disabled. No white space on iPad or iPhone except for iPhone X. I think it might be something related to the Safe Area thing.

[image]

Comment: are you using storyboards? have you looked at safe areas?

Comment: I use storyboard. `Bounce On Scroll/Zoom` are all disabled. No white space on iPad or iPhone except for iPhone X. I think it might be something relating to the Safe Area thing...

Comment: If you set the constraint to go past the safe area and to the end of the super view then it might work but you really haven’t given enough info so it could be many things

Comment: Share your code and storyboard design. So I can provide you complete solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I solved this issue in non-elegant way. But it works like a charm. (I tried all other answers. Thank for your help, however those answers don't seem to work in my case.)

```
var leftMargin: CGFloat = 0
var rightMargin: CGFloat = 0

if Device.isPhone() && Device.IS_5_8_INCHES() {
    self.leftMargin = 44
    self.rightMargin = 44
}

let frame = CGRect(
    x: (self.view.frame.width - self.leftMargin - self.rightMargin) * CGFloat(pageIndex),
    y: ...
)
```

Answer (score 34):

This spacing is from safe area, which is applied to left/right of UIScrollview as content insets in landscape orientation on iPhone X, which can be seen using read-only property `UIScrollview.safeAreaInsets`.

**Following line can be used to get rid of safe area insets when you dont need:**

`UIScrollview.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never`

The default value being `UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentBehavior.automatic` includes safe area layout guide margins as content insets.

Note: auto layout constraints has nothing to do with the insets, its just iOS 11 UIScrollview content insets adjustment behavior.

Comment: Makes no difference to me. My images on my scrollview still are being squished inside the safe area and won't extend to the edges for all sides.

Answer (score 5):

Setting the constraint relative to `safeArea` is good practise for iPhone-X. 
This is how apple says -

> When the view is visible onscreen, this guide reflects the portion of
>   the view that is not covered by navigation bars, tab bars, toolbars,
>   and other ancestor views.

In your case you are giving constraints `leading` & `trailing` of `scrollView` with `safeArea`, Not `superView`

Hence if you take risk giving constraint to `superview` instead of `safeArea` your object content may clipped, specially when you rotate left, content from the left most will clip under top notch of iPhone-X.

[image]

[Apple doc for safeAreaLayoutGuide](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/2891102-safearealayoutguide)

Comment: In **iPhone-X**, For prevent object clipped from corner, notch- **iOS11+** comes with `safeArea`

Comment: I forget select "Use Safe Area Layout Guides". However I am not able to get the the width of margin of the white bars to the left or right of the safe area.

Comment: @zsong, You can watch [wwdc2017/204/](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/204/) for more reference.

Comment: @AamirR see this for VFL https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46479288/swift-safe-area-layout-guide-and-visual-format-language

Answer (score 0):

[Safe Area Layout](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/2891102-safearealayoutguide) is responsible for this white space.

**1st Option:**

Ignore safe area layout for your scrollview and set scrollview's constraints with respect to its super view (or main view). Scrollview automatically handle safe area inset for contents while scrolling.

Landscape View:

[image]

Portrait View:

[image]

**2nd Option:**

I do not recommend to remove/change safe area layout for your scroll view and an alternate solution that can solve white space visibility issue:

- Set blue background color (that you've applied for your scroll view) to your main view of your view controller, *if scroll view is covering entire screen*.
- set clear color background for your scroll view

Add this code in your `viewDidLoad`

```
@ IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView!

override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow // set here blue color that you've applied for your scroll view 

    self.scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear 
}
```

[image]

Here are good reference answers regarding Safe Area Layout, for better understanding:

- [Safe Area of Xcode 9](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45334411/5638630)
- [Use Safe Area Layout programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46318300/5638630)